# Visual studio plugin shows no visual data

Tags: visual-studio, plasticscm

I have since a couple of weeks following problem in visual studio 2019.
I've installed the latest version of plastic scm and i see the plastic scm toolbar. When i click a button in this toolbar the tabpage apears but no data is beeing shown. In the header of the tabpage the data is shown like for example 5 pending changes but the page stays blank.

Are there others that experiencing the same issue?
I have upgrade and downgraded several times.

[image]

Comment: Could you reach us at support@codicesoftware.com? The first thing is to be sure that the plugin is properly uninstalled(we can also manually remove it from the installation). Then once, we confirm it's uninstalled, if you install the last Plastic version, you should be able to use the plugin in VS2019

Comment: Dear Carlos,
a complete uninstall and re-install was the sollution.